# Multicast UDP communication from WSL 2 to windows of same machine

Tags: udp, windows-subsystem-for-linux, multicasting

I am trying to establish communication between WSL2 to windows and vice versa on same machine using multicast UDP socket.

Sender is sending the message successfully but receiver is not receiving. Please help me to identify what is the issue and how it can be fixed.

The code I have tried is https://gist.github.com/hostilefork/f7cae3dc33e7416f2dd25a402857b6c6

Comment: You should post details of  your environment, how did you build programs, and how did you run them, and what are concrete issues ?